# if there is any other approach when I can load all the facts in parallel once all the dimensions load is completed in Snowflake

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a set of tables to load from file to stage and then to dimensions and finally to Fact.
I used to tasks to load the data from files in s3 to stage, which I could do in parallel.
Then I have loaded the dimension tables from stage in parallel using the same tasks approach.
Now facts has to be loaded only after loading all the dimensions. Is there a way in tasks where we can say that start the facts load only after loading all the dimension tables.
OR
if there is any other approach when I can load all the facts in parallel once all the dimensions load is completed.

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake isn't really designed to be an ETL orchestration tool. But it does integrate fairly well with many tools out there. Open source and otherwise.

To really manage schedules and dependencies and parallelization like this, you'll need another tool to help manage that.

Comment: But there is an object by name Tasks through which we can schedule. But there is no way I saw that there is something that says after completing all the dimensions load, load the Fact.

Comment: Yes, you can do basic scheduling to run scripts. and you can have those scripts call other scripts, which might get you some basic funtionality that you are looking for. But for true dependency management, you'll probably want something more.